# Не могу превратить строку в лист Python

Tags: python, list

Имеется вот такого рода строка

```
a = '123 132 321 312'
```

Как мне превратить ее в лист, чтобы он был вот такого вида

```
b =  [123, 132, 321, 312]
```

я пытался сделать обычный `append` и `extend`

но это не помогло :с

Comment: `list(map(int, a.split()))`

Comment: Извращенный вариант: `ast.literal_eval('[{}]'.format(a.replace(' ',',')))`

Comment: @MaxU огромное спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.

Текст в список, пробелы как разделитель:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 19 2017, 23:26:14)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Android Clang 5.0.300080 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text="123 321 213 312"
>>> text.split()
['123', '321', '213', '312']
>>>
```

и если нужны именно цифровые значения:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in text.split()]
[123, 321, 213, 312]
>>>
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html